# I know that mathematical general definition of wave in One dimension is $y(x,t)=f(x\pm vt)$

Tags: waves

I know that mathematical general definition of wave in One dimension is $y(x,t)=f(x\pm vt)$.
Now I don't know that  what this function $f$.for example $f$ can be $f:[-1,+1] \to \mathbb{R} : f(x)=x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is meant to be any *arbitrary* function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

This can be understood from the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Wave_equation_in_one_space_dimension)
$$\frac{\partial^2 y(x,t)}{\partial t^2}=v^2\frac{\partial^2 y(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$$
which describes the underlying physics of a wave.

The most general solution of this differential equation is
$$y(x,t)=f_1(x+vt)+f_2(x-vt)$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are *arbitrary* functions.

Comment: I think these functions must be twice differentiable right?

Comment: @IamWill yes, i think so. But I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: @IamWill I'd argue they need to be twice differentiable to solve the wave equation, but that I'd still call discontinuous examples waves (eg triangle waves) since the propagate like waves.

Comment: @jacob1729 I think this has to be with weak solutions of the wave equation. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829794/does-dalemberts-solution-ux-t-fx-ctgxct-of-the-wave-equation-remain

Comment: So if $f$ be $[-1,+1] \to \mathbb{R}$ then $y(x,t)=f(x\pm vt)$ is'not wave? all right?

Comment: @justin7 Then it is still a wave, just restricted to the range $[-1,+1]$.